# How to find the remote repo branch which i used earlier to checkout the remote repo url

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I am running a Jenkins job and I have already done the checkout of a git url with a particular branch.
Now in next stage i want to fetch the git remote repo url and the checkout branch.

for getting the remote repo url I am using this command to directly get the url:-
`git config --get remote.origin.url`
But I am not sure which command to use for getting the checkout branch name.
I tried `git branch -r`  but this is giving all the branch names.

Can someone please tell the command if there is any from where I can directly fetch the git remote repo checked out branch.

Comment: `git status` reports the current branch. `git branch --list -vv "mybranch"` shows upstream  of `mybranch`

Answer (score 1):

Use `git reflog`. It gives you a history of recent HEAD moves.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Git version `1.8.5` or greater, you can use the following command:

```
$ git status -sb
## mybranch...origin/mybranch
```

where

```
-s, --short           show status concisely
-b, --branch          show branch information
```